# How to generate pcm audio file by setting 20 bit depth?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ms-media-foundation

### No option using ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to generate audio data. I am using following command

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.wav -ar 44100  -acodec pcm_s16le  -ac 1 out.wav
```

but there is no option to convert to 20 bit depth pcm audio. (something like pcm_s20le).

I want to perform some operations on apple codec (e.g. encoding pcm audio data to alac).

On ALAC source: http://alac.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/ReadMe.txt , it has been mentioned like this;

> Apple Lossless supports the following features
>   1. Bit depths 16, 20, 24 and 32 bits.

### Media Foundation on windows throwing exception for 20 bit depth

I tried sample encoding and transcoding application mentioned on MSDN https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-transcode-sample-f7ba5269

with following configuration but it failed

```
spTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 20);
```

NOTE: but i put 16 instead of 20; it created smoothly.

Is there any way to generate such 20 bit PCM audio? What is so special about 20 bit depth that it is not being considered on ffmpeg and media foundation but on apple codec?

Answer (score 3):

If you are limited to using ffmpeg here are its available bit depths

```
ffmpeg -sample_fmts
```

which gives you this

```
name   depth
u8        8 
s16      16 
s32      32 
flt      32 
dbl      64 
u8p       8 
s16p     16 
s32p     32 
fltp     32 
dblp     64
```

If you are free to roll your own solution its a matter of bit shifting and bit masking which is not too hard to master

if you google :

```
alac command line encoder
```

seems there is a tool which may help you :  [qaac](https://github.com/nu774/qaac)

Answer (score 2):

One key difference with 20-bit audio is that it doesn't pack nicely into bytes. 16-bit packs into 2 bytes, 32-bits into 4 bytes and 24 can either be packed into 3 bytes alone or 3 bytes within a 4 byte integer. You'll find that it is pretty common for 24-bit audio to be packed into a 4 byte integer such that one byte is just ignored. This makes it easier for software programs to stride through the audio using ints and casting.

Now consider how 20 bit audio would need to be stored. Either your going to store it in a 3 byte or 4 byte format ignoring the extra bits or its going to be packed in tight making it painful to pull the samples back out (since 1 sample is going to be 2 bytes plus a nibble and the next sample is going to be a nibble then 2 bytes and so on). For that reason it is extremely unlikely that 20-bit audio would ever be stored tightly packed.

With that in mind, if you just write out your wave file as 24-bit into 3 or 4 bytes and then ignored the extra 4 bits at the lsb then it is the same as a 20-bit waveform would be (except for possible dither).

I would just avoid 20-bit all together as it is not broadly supported. A possible workaround though would be to take the wave file output from ffmpeg and then modify the header to indicate 20-bit audio instead of 24. It should be a 2 byte word at offset 32.

Comment: bit depth of 20 is prior to compression so this argument may not apply

Comment: @ScottStensland. I'm not following you.